# How to clear all items of QListView

Tags: qt, qlistview

I searched a lot but I could not understand how to clear all items of `QListView`?

I used `QStringListModel` and `QStringList` to fill it.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can either use `model.setStringList( QStringList{} )`, or manually delete the rows with `model.removeRows( 0, model.rowCount() )`.

Answer (score 3):

This is working fine for me.

`model1->removeRows( 0, model1->rowCount());`

Comment: This answer, arriving just short of 6 years after the accepted answer, offers no useful information that isn't already provided in that answer.